# Does SonarQube 5.1.1 Support integration test coverage?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, integration-testing, code-coverage

I have verified SonarQube + jacoco analyzer's integration test coverage using v `6.1` and jacoco maven plugin `0.7.7.201606060606`

This works as expected and is able to list coverage by integration tests.

We have a SonarQube server running at version `5.1.1` does anyone know if that version of SonarQube is capable of showing integration test coverage numbers when using agents at `0.7.7.201606060606`?

Answer (score 3):

Reading JaCoCo report is done by the sonar java analyzer (so the sonarqube version is a rather indirect information here).

JaCoCo produces binary report and last incompatibility introduced was in 0.7.6 and that was handled in sonar java analyzer 3.4.

So if you use any version of SonarQube with a java analyzer with a version greater than 3.4 you should be fine to analyze JaCoCo reports produced with version 0.7.7

However given that 5.1.1 is not the latest LTS I would recommend you to upgrade to at least 5.6 and use latest sonar java analyzer.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a jacoco analyzer version that is capable of analyzing integration tests and is compatible with Java analyzer on sonar 5.1.1